# Problem on Emissivity and absorptivity

Tags: thermal-radiation

I have read the radiation chapter, where I have been introduced with the terms emissivity and absorptivity. emissivity tells about the ability to emit heat energy as thermal radiation compare to a black body. and absorptivity is the amount of heat absobed by body devided by the incident heat energy .but my question is ,are these emissivity and absorptivity constant or depends on temperature?
Actually I had a misconception that these quantities are intrinsic property of body 
If I have really wrong concept and they depends on temperature then tell me and 
Tell me how they depends on temperature 
I mean I need The mathematical expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a way, these are intrinsic properties of a material that depend on temperature. The temperature of the object dictates what a black body curve looks like and which wavelengths are emitted in what amounts. The emissivity of a material is not always uniform across all wavelengths, which means at different temperatures, you might get different emission profiles depending on the emissivity of the material at each wavelength along the curve. Similarly, the absorptivity can differ with wavelength. This means the absorptivity and emissivity values for a material might be not just different, but variably different. So the material might absorb well at the wavelength of incident radiation and emit poorly at its current temperature, but as a result, it may then heat up into a blackbody range where it is a good emitter. Furthermore, it also means the amount of energy the material absorbs (when pointed at a blackbody object) could depend on the temperature of the object it is pointed at.

There is no mathematical relation to provide you. Absorptivity and emissivity are intrinsic properties of a material. We test materials and empirically find the wavelength dependence of those values. It varies greatly from material to material, which means any time you want to use a different material, you should look up the $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ values for the wavelengths you expect to be relevant. Usually, however, it is sufficient to look up wavelength ranges, such as visible light, near IR, UV, etc.

Comment: I think your answer mixes up emission and emissivity.   It seems that you are taking emissivity as independent of temperature, a consequence of which is that the emission spectrum varies with temperature.  I would guess (but I'm not sure) that emissivity and absorptivity are only slightly dependent on temperature, that dependence due to thermal expansion.

Comment: Can it be mathametically shown?

Comment: @garyp I get what you're saying and you're probably right. I'm saying it depends on temperature indirectly. That is, there is a value $\epsilon(\lambda)$ and a $\lambda(T)$. But you're right that I am not saying it is dependent in the way that it changes directly because of a change in temperature

Comment: @user101134 Yes.  The simplest (ignoring thermal expansion) quantum mechanical expression depends only on the matrix elements between the energy eigenstates of the system.  That is,  there's no dependence on temperature, only on the electronic structure of the material.

Answer (score 3):

The figures below support Jim's statement.

[image]

Figure 1: The specific spectral radiation of a black (Schwarzer Strahler), grey (grauer Strahler) and real body (realer Strahler) at the same temperature and different wavelengths $\lambda$.

[image]

Figure 2: Specific spectral radiation of black bodies ($\varepsilon=1$) at different temperatures and wavelengths $\lambda$. According to Wien's displacement law. Note the wavelengths of sunlight are roughly at $380-780\ \mathrm{nm}$.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BlackbodySpectrum_loglog_de.svg).

Comment: Please include a link/reference to where you got those images from. Thank you for your collaboration :-)