# Why do materials have different Emissivity and Absorptivity?

Tags: thermal-radiation

I read this

[Problem on Emissivity and absorptivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267660/problem-on-emissivity-and-absorptivity)
but I am still wondering, why for example "white paint is quoted as having an absorptivity of 0.16, while having an emissivity of 0.93"

According to Kirchhoffs Law, absorptivity = emissivity coefficient (for all wavelengthts in Equilibrium temperature)

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation

it is a little bit explained, but I still do not get it.

So if I plot the emissivity and aborptivity of my white paint for T=300K over all wavelenghts for a given temperature, then they should match identical? If I raise the temperature to T=350 K the shape will Change, but both will be identical.

So how comes, that they have different values? I guess, that the emissivity depends on the body's temperature, whereas the absorptivity depends on the temperature of the surrounding/sun . But still, a Body should have the same radiative characteristics according to Kirchhoff

Who can help me?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Did you read the paragraph directly after the one you quoted, which states "This is because the absorptivity is averaged with weighting for the solar spectrum, while the emissivity is weighted for the emission of the paint itself at normal ambient temperatures."  It then goes on to discuss the math.  Perhaps this was still unclear to you, but perhaps you did not see that.

Comment: But then I am wondering: if I have a heated aluminium plate with 300 Kelvin and a black painted plate with 500 K. And now I have to define the emissivity and the absorptivity of each material. Then I have to weight the spectrum of the 500 K plate with the thermal absorptivity of the heated aluminium plate, which absorbs radiation of the 500 K plate. The same I would have to do the other way round: weight absorptivity of the black plate for the 300 Kelvin plate's spectrum? This would cause a lot of data to generate in experiments?