# Emissivity and absorptivity relation question

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

This question is related to another discussion [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/267660/problem-on-emissivity-and-absorptivity) about emissivity of bodies.  What interested me is to verify what extend the wavelength between emissivity and absorption is conserved at thermal equillibrium. That is , emissivity is produced only from electromagnetism with wavelengths range absorbed?

I hope the point of my question is clear. But just in case, another way to lay my question.  Is it possible for a narrow bandwith of radiation and x joules of energy center at a wavelength   produces the  emission with the same amount of energy but a bandwidth centered at a very different place  (up or down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a narrow bandwith of radiation and x joules of energy center at a wavelength produces the emission with the same amount of energy but a bandwidth centered at a very different place

If I understand correctly, you are asking about a greenhouse effect.   The
'narrow bandwidth' of incoming thermal radiation may be balanced by outgoing
radiation when a body is at radiative thermal steady state, but the
outgoing radiation is characterized by the temperature of the body,
NOT by the temperature of the source of incoming radiation, so will have different
spectral band character.   Both the temperature and the emissivity 
determine thermal radiant emission.

Earth, at a thermal steady state, shines thermally at IR and microwave
wavelengths, but is warmed mainly by solar (white/visible light) wavelengths.
The power in those two flows is in different spectral regions.

If Earth were really at equilibrium with Sol, it would be at the same
temperature; steady-state is a better name for the thermal resting
temperature between that of Sol and the black void.

Comment: Thank you!! Very instructive. I was not specifically thinking about greenhouse but any general radiation.  But was very instructive indeed!  Now that you have clarify the position of the emission bandwidth with respect to the original absorption, that role and what is the difference from fluorescence and phosphorescence.  They are also emission with a bandwidth displaced at a different position too?

Comment: Fluorescence and phosphorescence come from a large energy excitation (UV light, for instance) of an atom, which (as it relaxes from the excited state) goes through a multiplicity of transitions.  The quantum effect of the high-energy incoming photon is to make a cascade of less-energy photons (redder) and heat energies.   Fluorescence results when one highly-likely step of the inevitable decay of the excited state is visible (and can escape the material).   The fluorescent photon is lower energy than the excitation, always, but isn't the only photon in the series (so energy is conserved).